# Use file patterns inside a variable to list files [BASH]

Tags: regex, bash, shell, ls

I want to list all files in some directories, so I want to create an array of all the directories and list them recursively in a loop. But,

```
ls /home/user/{*.txt,*.sh}
```

lists all the files correctly. But when I use

```
location="/home/user/{*.txt,*.sh}"
ls $location # Error
ls "$location" # Error
ls ${location} # Error
```

it gives me an error saying no such file exists. Also, the second method is working just fine if there is only `location="/home/user/*.sh"`. Can someone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because brace expansion is done before variable substitution.

https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html#Shell-Expansions

Maybe the following workaround can help using extended globs

```
shopt -s extglob
location="/home/user/*.@(txt|sh)"
ls $location
```

or

```
location="/home/user/@(*.txt|*.sh)"
```

Comment: Neat and simple. Did not know about the extended regex fields. Thanks! More about it [here](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-extended-globbing).

Comment: it's not regex but glob pattern, different syntax (weaker), if you can update the title to be clearer : In the question it is the brace expansion.